# Cell ID info on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cellid

Is it possible to get Cell ID information on iPhone SDK 3.0?

Comment: a CellID is the unique number of a GSM cell for a given operator. Your phone is always connected to a Cell, and by nowing this number, you know the Cell, and by knowing the position of the cell, you know where you are. There is some accuracy issue, as the cell can cover from several hundreds of meters to several kilometers, but this could be a very good starting point to locate yourself.
*from http://www.opencellid.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't get any info about the radio information. Not the about the cell tower or the phone itself.

If you have a need for such functionality you should [file](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your location, use the [Core Location API](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/) - this will use the best available information (eg GPS, Cell towers, Wi-fi network geo-ip lookup) to locate the device. You can specify desired level of accuracy and it will supply you with latitude and longitude.